# Is there a way to use a variable when defining an array?

Tags: bash

So I was trying to test something to get around argument list too long issues when storing large files as variables.

```
lets_build_something_together () 
{ 
    file_name="$@";
    short=$(basename "${file_name}" | sed -e 's/ /_/g');
    unset make_file_array;
    while read file_array; do
       export make_file_array_${short}+=($(<${file_array}));
    done < <(split --verbose -b 1024 "${file_name}" | awk -F\' '/file/{print $2}')
}
```

This is giving a syntax error due to the `(' fort the array.   When defining a new array I found that i can use export make_file_array_${short}=value

example:

```
$ export bar=foo
$ export ${bar}=wtf
$ declare -p foo
declare -x foo="wtf"
```

I can then concatenate the two strings with:

```
$ export ${bar}+=wtf
$ declare -p foo
declare -x foo="wtfwtf"
```

However I don't seem to be able to do this with an array.

```
$ unset bar
$ declare -a bar
$ export ${foo}+=(valueone)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ declare -p bar
declare -a bar
```

I should be able to do this though I believe as demonstrated:

```
$ export bar+=(foo)
$ export bar+=(demo)
$ export foo=bar
$ declare -p bar
declare -ax bar=([0]="foo" [1]="demo")
$ declare -p ${foo}
declare -ax bar=([0]="foo" [1]="demo")
```

Is it possible to use a variable when defining another variable for an array or is this a bug?

Does anyone know of a way to have part of the variable name with an array defined like this be another variable?

Comment: are you asking for [dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48751711)?

Comment: Yes, pretty much the goal of it is to basically store a file as an array and i want to use basename on the file and have that be part of the array name but it throws a syntax error when i have +=(

Comment: Does `readarray` solve the problem? `readarray ar_$var <file`

Comment: !!  It does thanks so much, man I should really use help more often.  Feel free to throw that in as an answer and I'll set it as accepted answer.